# Своё ContextMenu у ячейки DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток!
Пишу софтину, столкнулся с проблемой, надо присвоить каждой ячейке DataGrig'a свое контекстное меню вместо стандартного:
[image]
Код:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CRow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" Margin="0,46,0,0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1152" Name="MainDataGrid" CellEditEnding="MainDataGridCellEditEnding" SelectedCellsChanged="MainDataGridSelectedCellsChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="30" Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" Header="№" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="40" Binding="{Binding Path=Tags}" Header="Tags" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="250" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="ID"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="390" Binding="{Binding Path=OriginalText}" Header="Original"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="390" Binding="{Binding Path=Translation}" Header="Translation"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Command="Cut" Header="Cut"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Command="Copy" Header="Copy"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Command="Paste" Header="Paste"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>-->
        </DataGrid>
```

P.S Можно ли перехватывать выделеный текст в ячейке DataGrid'а? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я погуглил и сам нашел такое решение

```
    <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CRow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" Margin="0,46,0,0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1152" Name="MainDataGrid" CellEditEnding="MainDataGridCellEditEnding" SelectedCellsChanged="MainDataGridSelectedCellsChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="CellContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Command="Undo" Header="Undo">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/Undo.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Command="Redo" Header="Redo">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/Redo.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Command="Cut" Header="Cut">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/Cut.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Command="Copy" Header="Copy">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/Copy.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Command="Paste" Header="Paste">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/Paste.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <Separator></Separator>
                <MenuItem Header="Add in Translation Database"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Search in Translation Database"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="30" Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" Header="№" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40" Binding="{Binding Path=Tags}" Header="Tags" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="250" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="ID">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CellContextMenu}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="390" Binding="{Binding Path=OriginalText}" Header="Original">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CellContextMenu}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="390" Binding="{Binding Path=Translation}" Header="Translation">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CellContextMenu}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, проще всего использовать `DataFridTemplateColumn` с [`CellTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate.aspx). Там вы сможете указать свой `DataTemplate` для каждой ячейки. А уж template может содержать контекстное меню, тултипы, цвета, рамочки, форматирование, что угодно.